# (C++) Longer Strings of Arithmetic Operators

Tags: c++, math

So I'm well aware of simplification rules that abridge code for simplicity, space, etc.  But as those arithmetic operator strings increase, how do we implement combined assignment operators?

Example:  Add `y*5` to `x`, store in `x`

Can be written as `x = x + (y*5)` and compressed into `x += (y*5)`.

My question is can you go even further and rewrite it as `x += y*5` ?

Or something akin to `a -= b + 2` being equivalent to `a -= (b+2)`

I'm planning a few left-field questions and wanted to confirm how order of operations was translated in more detail within C++ before I proceeded.  Thanks

Comment: A simple google search for [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) would have told you what you needed.

Comment: If you're willing to field a question for further clarification:  do we [ever] take into account longer mathematical strings that might need parenthesis from order of operations?  Most of the links and sites found successively from them remove all parenthesis regardless.

For example:
How would I use combined assignment operators to distinguish between x = 2*x + 4  and x = 2*(x+4)?  
What about long successive chains?  y = 3 * y + (4 *c) / (a * 5)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can remove all of those parentheses.

See this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly (and interpreting precedence) it usually only combines with the first set of operands and afterwards, normal parenthetical statements are required?

Such as: x = x + 2 * b - (4 / 9)    ==   x += 2 * b - (4/9)

Comment: @MissingMaths You don't need those parentheses too. You should really try to understand what operator precedence is and how it works.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm fighting 30 years of mathematics' order of operations.  I get the levels, I'm just struggling with expanded expressions with multiple operators.  Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run the code?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int x = 10;
  int y = 2;
  x += y * 2;
  std::cout << x << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Clearly gives `14`, and

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int x = 10;
  int y = 2;
  x += y * 2;
  int x1 = 10;
  x1 += (y * 2);
  std::cout << (x == x1) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Yields `1`, so you can rewrite. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ironically no I didn't run any code (*dolt).  It was a response to a quiz I gave and wasn't prepared.  First time computer teacher, long time math - ergo my knowledge of c++ order of operation (or precedence) needed a refresher.  Thank you.